# Tweepy MyStreamListener is called even when the person isn't tweeting?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am making a Tweepy program using StreamListener that waits for an account to tweet, saves the tweet as a txt file, replaces characters and then tweets the update txt file.

When I set the account to my own, @Bobwont, it works fine. Waits for @Bobwont to tweet, saves tweet as txt file, replaces characters and tweets the text.

When I set the account to @Zackfox, it seems to pull tweets from his profile instead of waiting for him to tweet. I'm not sure how to explain. I have posted my code and the terminal process.

Please let me know if you need more information.

zabkfox.py:

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'):
            print('retweet')
        else:
        #print data
            with open('tweet.txt','w') as tf:
                tf.write(status.text)

            with open('tweet.txt','r') as tf:
                contents = tf.read()
                newcontents = contents.replace('c','\U0001F171\uFE0F')

            print(newcontents)
            api.update_status(newcontents)

        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status.text)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(follow=['1700626069'])
```

terminal:

```
Documents/zabkfox/zabkfox.py 
this is my twitter bot
retweet
retweet
@za️kfox I liked this and then unliked this.  I had a good ️hu️kle. This is why I'm on twitter.
retweet
@za️kfox @bluefa️ebleedem Songs wa️k af
retweet
retweet
retweet
retweet
```

It seems to only be doing it with tweets where he replies. But it shouldn't be pulling his tweets anyway. It should wait for him to tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix:

Turn out it was picking up tweets where someone else had replied to him. I simply added this elif statement to work around it:

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
def on_status(self, status):

    if hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'):
        print('retweet')

    elif hasattr(status, 'in_reply_to_user_id'):
        print('reply')

    else:
    #print data
        with open('tweet.txt','w') as tf:
            tf.write(status.text)

        with open('tweet.txt','r') as tf:
            contents = tf.read()
            newcontents = contents.replace('c','\U0001F171\uFE0F')

        print(newcontents)
        api.update_status(newcontents)

    return True
```